# Bootstrap Datetimepicker set date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using a [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) from Eonasdan which works fine so far.

I have a HTML element like this

```
<div id="datetimepicker"></div>
```

and use the datetimepicker function like this:

```
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    stepping: 5,
    locale: "de"
});
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I want to update the date via Javascript using the [date](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) function. My try looks like this:

```
$("#datetimepicker").data("DateTimePicker").date("2016-01-01");
```

Unfortunately this only returns a large object and does not alter the visible date in any way. This object is returned

```
Object { destroy: c/l.destroy(), toggle: c/ha(), show: c/ga(), hide: c/ba(),
    disable: c/l.disable(), enable: c/l.enable(), ignoreReadonly: c/l.ignoreReadonly(),
    options: c/l.options(), date: c/l.date(), format: c/l.format(), 40 weitere… }
```

Using a different time format or taking only date and no time or whatsoever does not help either.

None of the suggested solutions I found on various websites have solved my problem. I don't know whether I have to update the element? If so, how do I do it? I could not find any hint in the docs...

It is not an option to use the defaultDate since I need to do this process twice with two different dates.

Comment: can you modify this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Cx70Y2moVVwPingvvN30?p=preview to reproduce the problem. First get it working without the setting...or you can create a fresh plnkr and update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) you can use `string, Date, moment, null`, string and Date examples are below. Note default picker format.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date())
```

or

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date('1/11/2016 12:23:12')
```

Comment: both do not work. The first merely sets the time to zero and the second yield the exact same result as my version

Comment: Have you replaced `$('#datetimepicker1')` to `$('#datetimepicker')` ?

Comment: Visit [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) open up web browser console and following line `$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date('1/11/2016 12:23:12');`

Comment: I have replaced it and use the console for testing. Never worked

Comment: I think your format might work, let me check that. I need a couple of minutes for this

Comment: [inline](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline)
Following works perfectly 
`$('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").date('1/11/2016 12:23:12');`
`$('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").date('2/11/2016 12:23:12');`

Comment: Your second code snippet from the answer works, nice. My date format was complient with the ISO 8601 but that was apparently not the right format. Thank you very much!

Comment: this work $('#datetimepicker1').data("datetimepicker").date('1/11/2016 12:23:12') . case sensitive, my picked dtp https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/

Answer (score 3):

I have debugged a little bit and I found this solution and it's working for me.

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").setValue('2020-05-3')
```

You will get all functions of datepicker by consoling this `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker")`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, i'm real Necromancer, but i got same problem and .date() function does not help for me.
But, i found this:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").options({ defaultDate: newdate});
// newdate - could be Date, Moment or ISO string
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your HTML element should be an Input tag:

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

When the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: null,
            format: 'LT'
        });

})
```

You can set your date value via JavaScript.

`$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date())`

or set null value, which is showing empty value.

`$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(null)`

I tested it. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for someone who is trying $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(null)
and you get error .data is undefined. Then you can use below jugaad, I do not know how good it is, but it does worked out for me

```
function getDateTimeObj(ele) {
    if(ele && ele[0]){
        for(k in ele[0]){
            if(ele[0][k].hasOwnProperty('DateTimePicker')){
                return ele[0][k]['DateTimePicker'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
getDateTimeObj($('#datetimepicker')).date(null);
```