# Insert date using datepicker in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Using selenium VBA, I am uploading some data and there is a date which I need to insert using datepicker.
Here's the html of the webpage that has the datepicker
https://pastebin.com/yqf8H36k

I tried to use `SendKeys` to send the date directly but the datepicker popup appeared and nothing entered.

```
.FindElementById("date").SendKeys wsUpload.Range("B5").Value
.FindElementById("date").Click
Debug.Print .FindElementByXPath("//div[@role='period']").Attribute("innerHTML")
.FindElementByXPath("//div[@role='period']").Click
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: https://getdatepicker.com/4/ , https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367539, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761118

Comment: ^^ you have a bootstrap datepicker like link 1 in comment above. The second two links show how to "cheat" programmatically interact with it and inject your date. The format for the jquery part depends on what the format is for your datepicker.

Comment: I have no great idea about bootstrap. How can I get the link to the datepicker?

Comment: I put a link above you can use for demo (just scroll down the page - there's a date only section)

Answer (score 1):

I could find some java scripts that leads me to the solution

```
Dim dt As Object
Set dt = .FindElementByCss("input#date")
.ExecuteScript "window.scrollBy(0, 400)"
.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", dt
dt.Clear
dt.SendKeys wsUpload.Range("B5").Value
.SendKeys .Keys.Tab
```

And another easier solution

```
.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('date').value = '" & wsUpload.Range("B5").Value & "'"
```

Comment: ^^ or that :-) works. I am always suspicious of Excel when it comes to reading in dates from cells however.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my tutor.